# Does overriding operator== help to avoid rebuilding?

Tags: flutter

I have a stateless widget

```
class Foo extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  A(this.text);
  Widget build(BuildContext _) => Text(text);
}
```

Let’s say I create an instance of ‘Foo’ somewhere in the widget tree with (rarely) changing ‘text’. Of course, whenever I create a new instance of ‘Foo’ even if it has the same ‘text’, its ‘build’ will be called.

Will introducing an ’operator==‘ that checks ‘text’ avoid rebuilding?

EDIT: There is only one instance of ‘Foo’ placed in the widget tree, but it’s always a new instance with every parent build.

EDIT:

I think I found the location in the Flutter codebase in ‘framework.dart’:

```
if (child.widget == newWidget) {
    if (child.slot != newSlot)
      updateSlotForChild(child, newSlot);
    return child;
  }
```

So, if a Widget overrides the ‘operator ==‘, two instances of the same Widget class that are ‘equal’ will NOT mark the subtree as dirty and hence not trigger a subtree ‘build’.

Hence, override ‘operator ==‘ can help optimizing performance!

Can someone confirm that?

EDIT:

I opened a ticket at GitHub and ask the Flutter team to clarify "same" vs "equal" vs "identical" with respect to rebuilding of the widget tree.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/38740

Answer (score 0):

You wanna know if creating 2 instances of Foo() in different parts of the widget tree, and overriding ==  will assure that build() will be called only once? even if you have 2 separate objects?
I totally doubt that... although, we know that Flutter optimized the widget tree for all const instances,
if some parent widget rebuilds itself, const Stateless widgets children will not be rebuilt.

Comment: It’s the same location in the tree

Comment: @user3612643 same applies, 2 different instances are 2 different builds(). I dont know if this answers your question, maybe i misunderstood. In any case, is easy to try what you asked yourself, just put a print() inside the build() of that widget.

Comment: I added the lines of code that do the check and Flutter uses the “==“ operator there and not the “identical” operator. So your answer is wrong IMHO.